# How to filter data without using filter command google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

So I have the following data

```
Description Quantity Price
Light 2 5
LED Light 5 3
Books 10 2
```

Now I want to know the total price for all lights. I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
=arrayformula(sumproduct(a2:a5="*Light",b2:b5*c2:c5))
```

The *wildcard* * worked in functions like `countif`, but didn't seem to work in the `arrayformula`. `Filter` filters correctly, yet I want to know what line matches what quantity and what price, so I can't use `filter` either, because it only outputs the matching lines. So, what is wrong with my function?

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=sumproduct(B2:B10,C2:C10,--not(iserror(find("Light",A2:A10))))
```